# jQuery - Javascript in Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some problem with using jQuery

HTML

```
<div class="dnone team_data" id="team_<?php echo $allnum; ?>" style="padding: 10px; margin: 2px 0 2px 0; border: 1px solid <?php echo $site_color; ?>;">
<div class="ajax-json-loading"></div>
<div class="ajax-json-response"></div>
<table cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
            <b>Csapat vezető:</b>
        </td>
        <td class="team-leader-area">
            <input type="hidden" class="team-leader-hidden-id" value="<?php echo $value['leader']; ?>" />
            <div class="team-leader-id"><a href="http://lanseries.hu/index.php?oldal=profile&p_id=<?php echo $value['leader']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value['leader']; ?></a></div>
            <div class="team-leader-modify"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Módosít</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
            <b>Befizető címe:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['p_address']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table></div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.team-leader-modify a').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).text();
    if (action == 'Módosít') { //Option 1
        var value = $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-hidden-id').val();
        $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-id').html('<input type="text" name="leader-id" class="leader-id" value="'+value+'" /><input type="button" name="team-leader-mod-button" class="team-leader-mod-button" value="módosít" />');
        $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Mégse</a>');
    }
    if (action == 'Mégse') { //Option 2
        var value = $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-hidden-id').val();
        $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-id').html('<a href="http://lanseries.hu/index.php?oldal=profile&p_id='+value+'" target="_blank">'+value+'</a>');
        $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Módosít</a>');
    }
}); });
```

After I click the `a` after DOM loaded it shows the `option 1` correctly, but after I click the `a` in the `option 1` it doesn't show up the `option 2`.

Could you help me?

Thanks: Marcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, the problem is that you're inserting a new element into the DOM, so the `click` event handler won't be attached to it. You can use jQuery's `live` or `delegate` methods to attach an event handler to existing elements, and those added in the future:

```
$('.team-leader-modify a').live("click", function(){
    //Your function
});
```

Or, with `delegate`:

```
$('.team-leader-modify').delegate("a", "click", function(){
    //Your function
});
```

I would suggest using `delegate`, which offers better performance because jQuery doesn't have to monitor the entire DOM for new elements, just the selected element.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Hello again.
I've got again a problem. Could you help me about it too? http://pastebay.com/140796 Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "AJAX doesn't show any answer". I would suggest posting a new question with your new problem.

Comment: It doesn't do what I wrote to the `success` section.